# Multithreading: input queue processing

Tags: multithreading

**Multithreading question**

My solution/problem statement has two queue

Input queue in which buffers get enqueued continuous. 
`let's say buffer1,buffer2,buffer3...`

Output queue. 
In which buffers are stored in sequence of their arrival from input queue. `buffer1, buffer2,buffer3...`

I.e let's say I have three worker thread T1,T2,T3 which picks buffer1,buffer2,buffer3 respectively.

T2 completes first then T1 then T3

These buffers should be processed in multi threaded manner. Some algorithm is performed on these buffers. Algorithm processing time is very short(few milliseconds)

---

These buffers should be enqueued to output queue in sequence of arrival of buffer(deque time).

---

What I am thinking is to have.
Pick current time of when element is getting dequed stored in unordered map time as key and value is whether it's completed or not.  Whenever worker threads picks up or deque element from input queue it makes the map entry.

And whenever worker thread completes buffer processing it marks the map entry to be complete i.e time,complete and also check whether map entries before this entry is completed if it is completed it removes all the entries from map and puts into the output queue.

**Are there any problems with this approach ??
Are there any alternative implement ???
Thanks in advance for sharing your views.**

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps an idea is to use a [priority queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue) for your output.  You can enqueue items to the priority queue in any order from any thread, but when dequeueing items, you can get them in a certain order.  In your case, you can use the timestamp of every item's arrival in the input queue as a priority value.

And, of course, when you choose or implement a priority queue, make sure it is thread-safe.